Assign AcrPull role to Azure Container Registry in Bicep for Azure App Container
I created a container app, enabled for it managed identity and now I am trying to assign the AcrPull role to ACR for the managed identity but I get internal server error during deployment. Not sure what I am doing wrong! Actually following this  guide but there are only cli commands that i previously tried and worked good.
This is the part where I try to assign the role:
 resource acrPullRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
   name: guid(containerApp.id, 'AcrPull') // Unique name for the role assignment
   scope: acr
   properties: {
     principalId: containerApp.identity.principalId // Managed identity of the container app
   roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'AcrPull')
  }
}

And this are the other resources:
  resource acr 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-08-01-preview' = {
    name: acrName
    location: location
    sku: {
      name: 'Basic'
     }
    properties: {
    dataEndpointEnabled: false
    encryption: {
      status: 'disabled'
     }
    adminUserEnabled: true
   }
}


resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: containerAppName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    managedEnvironmentId: env.id
  configuration: {
  ingress: {
    external: true
    targetPort: 80
    allowInsecure: false
    traffic: [
      {
        latestRevision: true
        weight: 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
template: {
  containers: [
    {
      name: containerAppName
      image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/k8se/quickstart:latest'
      resources: {
        cpu: json('2.0')
        memory: '4Gi'
      }
    }
  ]
  scale: {
    minReplicas: 0
    maxReplicas: 1
  }
}
  }
 }


You should use the id of the role rather than the name: AcrPull => 7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d

Also what type of container app environment are you using?

I would suggest using a user assigned identity so you can grant the identity AcrPull role before deploying.

Please check the doc Azure Container Apps image pull with managed identity, it's recommended to share the error details.


Assign AcrPull role to Azure Container Registry in Bicep for Azure App Container

When you create a role assignment using Bicep, make sure to set the principalType as ServicePrincipal for the managed identity. Follow the MS DOC for more details.

#conainer app mangedidentity principal ID
param principalId string = '4fb6333333-4207-b4f3-a04e9754808c' 

resource acr 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: 'venkatacrtestdemo'
  location: 'eastus'
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
  }
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' =  {
dependsOn:[
    acr
  ]
  name: guid(acr.id, principalId, 'AcrPull')
  scope: acr
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d')
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}

az deployment group create --name "demoRGDeployment" --resource-group "ACR-RG" --template-file ./ACRRole.bicep


After executing the script, the AcrPull role was assigned to the managed identity of the container app.

Reference:  Role assignments
